# MYSQL want to compare two table and select data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
table 1
1
2
3
4

table 2
1
2
3
```

i want to select data from tables

table 1 have all data.
but table 2 may have all data or not.
so 
if table 1 data exits in table two data select table 2 data otherwise select table one data.

if table 1 data not exit table 2 select table 1 data.

how can do that?

Comment: Why dont you try some tools like Visual Data Comare from SQLyog

Answer (score 2):

You need `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
       COALESCE(t2.col1, t1.col1) AS col1,  -- prefer data from table_2 if exists
       COALESCE(t2.col2, t1.col2) AS col2,
       -- ...
FROM table_1 t1                  -- "table 1 have all data"
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2             -- "table 2 may have all data or not"
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT t2.col1, t1.col1
FROM 
    table_1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
```

Or, if full joins are not supported by your database, try [emulating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql).